503 Service Unavailable Jira
When try to access Jira restful link of my company with username and token.
getting below error says 503 Service Unavailable
Tried with basic auth in postman and getting 200 statuses but no data returning.
what could be the issue is someone explain is it either because of Firewall or MFA or SSL


Expected result: should return list issues
